# Why is my Firebase causing a me Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Why are these 3 lines causing a *How to fix Maximum call stack size exceeded* error in my MERN+Firebase app?

I also get non-stop   *at deepExtend (deepCopy.ts:71)* errors so something is recursive. I just don't know what?

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseKeys);
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const storage = firebase.storage();
```

JS file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Rating from '../components/Rating';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
import axios from 'axios';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { ReactMediaRecorder } from 'react-media-recorder';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';
import firebaseKeys from 'firebase';
const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:5000';

dotenv.config();
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseKeys);
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const storage = firebase.storage();
```

If I comment out the 3 lines and any reference to storage then the app loads but of course to change of using Firebase.

UPDATE: I have change the code per the comment below about putting Firebase into a wrapper component, but not sure what do with it. When I put the 3 firebase lines in the wrapper `FireStoreStuff` the issue went away. But it also means Firebase is NOT working as I don't know where to include it. Firebase isn't used until the USER clicks "UpLoad".

FULL CODE (I should also note that this app is as follows: Its an ecommerce app the main page shows all the products. This page having the issue is the "ProductScreen" so it is shown when you click on a product from the main page. So not sure if maybe React is building these firebase connections for each specific product?)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Rating from '../components/Rating';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
import axios from 'axios';
// import Product from '../components/Product';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { ReactMediaRecorder } from 'react-media-recorder';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';
// import firebase from 'firebase';
// import 'firebase/firestore';
import firebaseKeys from 'firebase';
// import admin from 'firebase-admin';
const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:5000';

dotenv.config();
// firebase.initializeApp(firebaseKeys);
// export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
// export const storage = firebase.storage();
// firebase.analytics();
// export const storage = firebase.storage(); {}
const FireStoreStuff = () => {
  const [firestore, fireStorage, setFirestore] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseKeys);
    setFirestore(firebase.firestore(), firebase.storage());
    // ...
  }, []);
};
const AudioPreview = ({ stream }) => {
  const audioRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('starting audioPreview ========');
    if (stream) audioRef.current.srcObject = stream;
  }, [stream]);

  if (!stream) return null;
  return <audio ref={audioRef} autoPlay controls />;
};

const VideoPreview = ({ stream }) => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('starting audioPreview ========');
    if (stream) videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
  }, [stream]);

  if (!stream) return null;
  return <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay controls />;
};

function Controls({ status, startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlobUrl }) {
  const [url, setURL] = useState('');
  async function uploadFile() {
    
    console.log('starting UPLOAD ========');
    const blob = await fetch(mediaBlobUrl).then((r) => r.blob());
    const path = '/recordings/one';
    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(path)
      .put(blob)
      .then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log('Uploaded complete');
      });

    firebase.storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL().then(setURL);
  }
  return (
    <Row>
      <span className='uk-text-meta'>{status}</span>
      <button className='uk-margin-small-left' type='button' onClick={startRecording} disabled={status === 'recording'}>
        Start
      </button>
      <button className='uk-margin-small-left' type='button' onClick={stopRecording} disabled={status === 'stopped'}>
        Stop
      </button>
      <button className='uk-margin-small-left' type='button' onClick={uploadFile} disabled={status !== 'stopped'}>
        upload
      </button>
      {url && (
        <a className='uk-margin-small-left' href={url} target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
          open
        </a>
      )}
    </Row>
  );
}

function RecordAudio() {
  return (
    <ReactMediaRecorder
      audio
      render={({ status, startRecording, stopRecording, previewStream, mediaBlobUrl }) => (
        <Row>
          {status === 'recording' ? (
            <AudioPreview stream={previewStream} />
          ) : (
            <audio src={mediaBlobUrl} controls autoPlay />
          )}
          <Controls
            status={status}
            startRecording={startRecording}
            stopRecording={stopRecording}
            mediaBlobUrl={mediaBlobUrl}
          />
        </Row>
      )}
    />
  );
}

function RecordVideo() {
  return (
    <ReactMediaRecorder
      video
      render={({ status, startRecording, stopRecording, previewStream, mediaBlobUrl }) => (
        <Row>
          {status === 'recording' ? (
            <VideoPreview stream={previewStream} />
          ) : (
            <video src={mediaBlobUrl} controls autoPlay />
          )}
          <Controls
            status={status}
            startRecording={startRecording}
            stopRecording={stopRecording}
            mediaBlobUrl={mediaBlobUrl}
          />
        </Row>
      )}
    />
  );
}

// function RecordScreen() {
//   return (
//     <ReactMediaRecorder
//       screen
//       render={({ status, startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlobUrl }) => (
//         <div>
//           <video src={mediaBlobUrl} controls autoPlay />
//           <Controls
//             status={status}
//             startRecording={startRecording}
//             stopRecording={stopRecording}
//             mediaBlobUrl={mediaBlobUrl}
//           />
//         </div>
//       )}
//     />
//   );
// }

// function handleClick(num) {
//   this.setState(num);
// }

const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('about to fetch product');
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      console.log('Below is the id param waht the fuck is it?');
      console.log(match.params.id);
      const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products/${match.params.id}`);

      setProduct(data);
    };
    fetchProduct();
    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
    socket.on('status-update', function (call) {
      const stext = document.getElementById('statusText');
      stext.innerText = call;
    });
    // CLEAN UP THE EFFECT
    // return () => socket.disconnect();
  }, [match]);
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <Link className='btn btn-light my-3' to='/'>
        Go Back
      </Link>
      <Row>
        <Col md={6}>
          <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
        </Col>
        <Col md={3}>
          <ListGroup variant='flush'>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h3>{product.name}</h3>
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <Rating value={product.rating} text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`} />
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>Price : {product.price}</ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>Description : {product.description}</ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Col>
        <Col md={3}>
          <Card>
            <ListGroup variant='flush'>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Price: </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
            <ListGroup variant='flush'>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Status: </Col>
                  <Col>{product.countInStock > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of Stock'}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Button
                  //   onClick={addToCartHandler}
                  className='btn-block w-100'
                  type='button'
                  disabled={product.countInStock === 0}
                >
                  Add To Cart
                </Button>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Copy Status: </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <h2 id='statusText'>Share</h2>
                    <button type='button' onClick={() => setState(1)}>
                      audio
                    </button>
                    <button type='button' onClick={() => setState(2)}>
                      video
                    </button>
                    {/* <button type="button" onClick={() => setState(3)}>
        screen
      </button> */}
                    {state === 1 && <RecordAudio />}
                    {state === 2 && <RecordVideo />}
                    {/* {state === 3 && <RecordScreen />} */}
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably wrap those three lines in a useEffect hook. By that you can control when these will be executed way more clearly.

Build a Wrapper component providing firestore and storage to all child components. Execute this "initializeApp" after the initial render of that wrapper component.

```js
const [firestore, setFirestore] = useState(undefined);
// ...

useEffect(() => {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseKeys);
    setFirestore(firebase.firestore());
    // ...
}, []);
```

In all child components using this `firestore`/`storage` you can react to it changing from undefined to something valid with other useEffect hooks.

Comment: Not sure how to build a wrapper component that gives it to the child components

Comment: @jdog I guess you should learn react then ;)